# Integrate Credit Card Payment in my website, How?

Tags: payment, credit-card

Can anybody help me, how to integrate credit card payment in website. A link for tutorial is very much appreciated. I've been stuck in this module for two days now. Thank you so much guys for your response.

Comment: Well first you have to decide which countries your buyers are from, choose a payment processor friendly to them. Then pick one with the most preferential rates. Then go to their API documentation and download script samples. Post back here when you have trouble implementing any payment processor's APIs. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many most popular payment gateways available like `PayPal`, `CyberSource`, `Google Checkout`.

this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php--net-25397) and [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/payment-system-with-paypal.html) may helps you to understand and gives you better direction on how to integrate PayPal in website.

You can also visit:

- [thesitewizard](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/creditcards.shtml)
- [payment gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_gateway)
- [zaakpay](https://www.zaakpay.com/developers/guide)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It is very much appreciated. I have tried that sir, but I failed. Is there a complete tutorial on how the proper integration of those payment processor? Thanks again. I hope you will mind answering my question.